# How to restore function overwritten by runkit_function_redefine? Halt running php process mightbe?

Tags: php, runkit

Its ok that I redefine a function (lets suppose `fsockopen`) but I have no idea how to restore it.

EDIT: Im thinking of just halting and restarting the current running PhP process, that might restore everything

Comment: Why would you want to redeclare fsockopen?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to restart. Better to use `runkit_function_copy` to clone the original function before you redefine it. Then you can easily restore it as needed.

Comment: restarting seems to be easier. Is this a solution for Windows? "posix_kill (getmypid(), 0);" but "posix_kill" is undefined

Comment: Bit confused. Just reload the page?

Comment: ok then, lets suppose we are unittesting. When the testcase has run, then should we restart the apache (tearDownAfterClass)

Comment: For unit testing, you're better off backing up the original function as I said before, then restoring it in tearDownAfterClass